# Как использовать переменные JS в качестве аргументов для функции MySQL INSERT?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, база-данных

Короче, я недавно решил написать небольшой сайт со встроенной БД для аккаунтов. Выбрал для основы я MySQL (вынудили обстоятельства). В нём я разбираюсь только немного, я почитал пару гайдов. И вот, я начал писать. Мне нужно было как-то вносить аккаунты и их данные в БД. Я пришел к логичному выводу - надо через INSERT вставить текущие данные полей для данных (они получены через DOM и сохранены в соответствующих переменных). Казалось бы, все просто, но вот я столкнулся с проблемой: я не могу внести переменные в качестве аргументов для команды INSERT. Как мне сделать это? Вот сам код:

```
const newUser = () => {
    let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
    let pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        database: "accbase",
        password: "пароль"
    });
    connection.connect({
        INSERT INTO users(name, balance, pass) VALUES(name, balance, pass);
    })
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Тут какая то путаница. DOM доступен в браузере пользователя. А MySQL из браузера не доступен, он доступен только из node.js запущенном на сервере. Сначала данные надо как то передать из браузера на сервер, через форму или ajax вызовом. И вот его уже обработать на сервере, получить переменные, связать с запросом, послать в mysql.

Comment: Вот я и пытаюсь узнать, как это сделать

Comment: гугл дает массу информации, например такую https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/code-your-first-api-with-nodejs-and-express-connect-a-database--cms-31699 статью. А вообще хорошо бы вам почитать какую нибудь книгу, потому что тут уже начинается не разработка сайта, а разработка отдельно сайта и бекэнда к нему. И это очень обширная тема на сотни страниц информации